# How to structure code for different user roles in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-4, software-design

I am developing an application which has a different user roles with different privileges. I have split up the views in terms of navigation, the main area and so on. In the navigation I have put `if` blocks and if the user has permission to the particular resource it will show up in the navigation otherwise it won't.

But what about the controllers? Should I create a `DashboardController` and when the user is at dashboard route, call the `index` method or `showDashboard` method and then check with `if` statements what data is supposed to be injected into the views? Or should I create different controllers for different users example `AdminDashboardController`, `ManagerDashboardController` and so on. What is the standard way to go about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should make diif diff according to role folder in view e.g 
admin, user, superadmin.
in view make three folder admin, user, superadmin .. and same as controller diff diff controller for every role  that will help you a lot to manage your code if you are developing a big application.

in routes also keep your routes separate according to roles..